# How can I move keyframes of rig control properties in the timeline

Tags: rigging, armature, select

Cannot select/unselect/move keyframes (in the timeline) of rig control properties of the free blender Rain rig. For example the FK/IK toggle switch, stretch toggle etc. The keyframes remain selected always as yellow rhombuses. Even deleting the keyframes (by Alt+I hovering over a particular property) won't affect these. How can I? Using versions 2.8 and 2.83. Please refer the image. [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hey! Here is the file[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=wPa7wlsW" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/wPa7wlsW/)

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden bones. Switch to *Pose* mode, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data*, unhide every layer, also unhide with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, and select all. Now you can move the keyframes.

[image]

For the *Protected Layers* check the explanation [here](http://urchn.org/post/protected-armature-layers).